# Pagination Current page/Total pages?

Tags: tumblr

I am in the process of making my first Tumblr theme and I'm a little confused about pagination.

I'm trying to make my pagination something like this:

Where there is (current page/total pages) with "NEXT" as the next page link on its right

[image: pagination in mind]

And when you are on the other pages, a "PREV" as the previous page link appears on its left.

[image: pagination on second page or other pages]

**CSS**

```
#pagi { 
  position:absolute; 
  z-index:10;
  margin-top:18px; 
  width:130px; 
  text-align:center; 
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
#pagi a { 
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
{block:Pagination}

<div id="pagi">
  {block:PreviousPage}
  <a href="{PreviousPage}" title="later posts">PREV</a>
  {/block:PreviousPage}

  {block:JumpPagination length="3"} 
  {block:CurrentPage}
  ({PageNumber})
  {/block:CurrentPage}
  {block:JumpPage}
  <a class="jump" href="{URL}">{PageNumber}</a> 
  {/block:JumpPage}
  {/block:JumpPagination}

  {block:NextPage}
  <a href="{NextPage}" title="earlier posts">NEXT</a>
  {/block:NextPage}
</div>

{/block:Pagination}
```

I thought i did it right, but instead it turned out like this:  [image: my attempt]

What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Current Page and Total Pages**

Sadly, the jump pagination won't work here. `{CurrentPage}` will give you the current page number. `{TotalPages}` will give you the total page count.

```
{block:Pagination}

<div id="pagi">
  <!-- Prev Page Link -->
  {block:PreviousPage} 
  <a href="{PreviousPage}" title="later posts">PREV</a>
  {/block:PreviousPage} 

  <!-- Page Counter -->
  <span class="counter">({CurrentPage}/{TotalPages})</span>

  <!-- Next Page Link -->
  {block:NextPage}
  <a href="{NextPage}" title="earlier posts">NEXT</a>
  {/block:NextPage} 
</div>

{/block:Pagination}
```

Comment: Oh it works!! I see that i shouldn't have put Jump Pagination too. Thanks so much!! :D @mikedidthis